# Jwplayer: Providing a path from home directory to play videos

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I have my jwplayer installed and this is my code:

```
<div class="video-container">
  <h3 style="color: #467AA7;padding-left: 800px;">Login</h3>
  <div class="video-body" style="padding-left: 700px;">
  <div id="myElement"> Loading the player...</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">jwplayer("myElement").setup({
     file : "/home/user/videos/login.mp4",});
  </script>
  </div>
  <p style="color: #467AA7;padding-left: 700px;font-size:12px; font-style:italic;"></p>
</div>
```

This is the path of my video : "`/home/user/videos/login.mp4`" but when i try to access my application it says **"Error Loading Media: File Not found"** as it is searching for `home/user/videos/login.mp4`in my application but not going to the server's path. 
My request is like this in the browser: www.myapp.com/home/user/videos/login.mp4 - 404 not found.

Can you please help me fixing the file path to access the videos from the server's path. 
Thanks

UPDATE: "./home/user/videos/login.mp4" doesn't work as well. It still stays in my application and passes it with the url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this instead:

```
file:///home/user/videos/login.mp4
```

**EDIT**: oh wait, you're requesting the page using HTTP. In that case: it's not gonna work. To your browser, those two resources (the html page and the movie file) exist in separate domains, and generally, cross-domain resource access will be blocked by your browser.

Comment: +1 for that, how do you think we can solve this. I have 10 websites and I cannot add videos in each and every application as it consumes a lot of space. So I need to have a common place where I can store all the vidoes and access that from all my applications.

Comment: You could put the movie file on a Dropbox account (just tested, that will work cross-domain). Or create a `videos.yourdomain.com` and enable CORS support in your server software (see http://enable-cors.org/)